# SQLite INSERT and jQuery - LOOPS out of sync

Tags: jquery, sqlite

I am trying to loop through an array and insert a DB record for each element in the array, but the code is looping through the array first, then executing all of the INSERT statements using the final values of the array.

Example, this array has 3 elements:

```
for(i=0;i < ary.length; i++)
{
  print('Processing element ' + i);
  var parm = ary[i];
  db.transaction(
       function(transaction)
       {
         transaction.executeSql(
        'INSERT INTO myTable ' +
        '(myValue) VALUES (?);',
         [parm],
         function()
         {
          print('Inserted element ' + parm);
         },
         errorHandler
         );    
       }
      );
```

What this yields on screen is:

```
Processing element 1
Processing element 2
Processing element 3
Inserted element 3
Inserted element 3
Inserted element 3
```

How can I get the INSERT statements to fire in order, as each element is processed?

Comment: Looks like the common for loop scoping issue. Your for loop is finishing before the inserts are happening. Solve it with an IIFE or using `$.each`/`array.forEach`

Comment: Using an IIFE took care of it. Thanks for the tip in the right direction.